# UIView frame sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitableview, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I am currently working on an application that has some ViewController with a button on it that pushes to a UITableViewController with Search Bar and Search Display controller. I have some data in the cells and that gets populated. I have added the following code to hide the search bar and also make it clearcolor when you do see it:

```
[[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperView];
[self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
CGRect newBounds = [[self tableView]bounds];
newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + searchBar.bounds.size.height;
[[self tableView] setBounds:newBounds];
```

Now this works when I am using the iOS simulator, but when I run it on my device and begin to scroll, either up or down, it crashes and gives me the following error:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code = EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode = 0xdefe)
```

I then enabled Zombie Objects to further debug and got this:

```
-[UIView frame]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x156b1430
```

When I take off:

```
[[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperView];
[self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

and run my application on my device again, it does not crash and works fine.

Anyone have any ideas whats going on and how this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did I get down voted? It was an honest question. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate/repost, I tried searching and didn't find anything.

Comment: at which ios version you are working?? And are you using objective c automatic reference counting??

Comment: @KamalSharma my simulator is running on iOS 6.1 and my device is on iOS 7. And yes, I am using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperView]; 

    //This Line remove search bar from view ,which means it is deallocated at that moment so when you again try to remove it ,,the app crash ..
  //  So,instead of this try to hide searchbar ,,

    Self. searchBar.hidden =YES;
```

Comment: I don't want the searchBar to be hidden necessarily. I want it to be a clear color so It blends in with the background color of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

I think UISearchBar has unsafeunretained reference of `[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];`

And You set the Bounds of `UITableView` then change frame of `UITableView`.
It would fire auto resizing and `layoutSubviews`.

So, UISearchBar's layoutSubviews method access `[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0].frame`
for layout or auto resizing.

It's not recommended that change view in `UIControls` from SDK.
There is an idea that Setting `hidden=YES` instead `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: I am not trying to hide my search bar. The reason that I changed it out of the frame is because I don't want it to be visible in the beginning. I have a button that launches the search bar, ie makes it visible. The user can also scroll up the table view and it will appear. The reason I am using `[[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperView];` is because if I only type out `[self.searchBar setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];` it doesn't work in both the Simulator and my Device.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. Got to this page, read the words 'zombie objects' in the question and remembered that I'd left zombie objects enabled. After disabling them, the problem went away. Now when I scroll my tableView, there's no crash.

This may be weird, but perhaps it will help someone...